# What is a word for an entity or number that will not modify something else?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for an entity or number that won't modify something?

Or in mathematical terms 1 won't modify another number if you multiply by it (2 * 1 = 2).

I would imagine you could also generalize this term outside of math but I can't think of an example.

Comment: I believe that an INERT material won't react chemically with any substance, and the NOBLE GASSES  are examples. But that's not my department.

Comment: I think we need a more concrete scenario.  There are many words like inconsequential, ineffective, useless,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Maths SE under 'terminology'.

Comment: neutral, identity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An [identity](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/identity) defined by Oxford Online as:

> *Mathematics* 
>   A transformation that leaves an object unchanged.

and

> An element of a set which, if combined with another element by a specified binary operation, leaves that element unchanged.

and

> *Mathematics* 
>   The equality of two expressions for all values of the quantities expressed by letters, or an equation expressing this, e.g. (x + 1)² = x² + 2x + 1.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Also note that the identity can be different for different operations. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element